# Pyside: Pass a var generated in a function to another function

Tags: python, function, pyside

The following functions are both activated by a clicked signal of a separate `QPushButton`. I want to give the user the possibility to choose a `.pdf` file, do some program specific edits and save it to a user defined location.

How can I make so that the path to the `.pdf` is passed to another function?

```
def select(self):
    dir = "."
    fileObjOpen = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select a .pdf file", dir=dir, filter="PDF Files (*.pdf)")
    fileObjOpenName = fileObjOpen[0]

    if (len(fileObjOpenName) > 1):
        path_to_pdf = fileObjOpenName

def save(self):
    dir = "."
    fileObjSave = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Where to save the new pdf file", dir=dir, filter="PDF Files (*.pdf)")
    fileNameSave = fileObjSave[0]

    if (len(fileNameSave) > 1):
        path_to_pdf = path_to_pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about `pyside`, but it seems like you're using a class since `self` is the first argument to each of your functions.  If that's the case, you can just set `path_to_pdf` as an attribute on the class instance.

e.g.

```
def select(self):
    #snip ...
    if len(fileObjOpenName) > 1:
       self.path_to_pdf = fileObjOpenName

def save(self):
    #snip ...
    if len(fileNameSave) > 1:
       path_to_pdf = self.path_to_pdf
```

If I've horribly misinterpreted this, let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your functions return something...:

```
def select(self):
    ...
    (filename, fileselector) = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(...)
    if filename:
        return filename
    return
```

By default, `select`, like any method or function in Python, will return `None`, so the last `return` is superfluous (but I like showing where it actually ends).

Now, you would call your `other_function` as `other_function(YourWidget.select())`.

You could also store the output of `.select()` in an attribute of your `QWidget`